# Add comma X characters after the Yth occurence of a comma

Tags: regex

I am trying to edit a file which has multiple lines in this format.

```
ATOM,9,HG,LEU,1,162.4,131.44,219.19,0,0,PROA
ATOM,10,CD1,LEU,1,163.3,130.88,219.73,0,0,PROA
ATOM,11,HD11LEU,1,163.54,130.77,219.97,0,0,PROA,
ATOM,12,HD12LEU,1,163.48,130.98,219.76,0,0,PROA,
```

For every string between the 2nd and 3rd occurrence of a comma `(e.g. HG, CD1, HD11LEU etc.)`, I want to add a comma after the last occurrence of a digit, provided there is a digit in the string and the digit is followed by a character `(e.g. HD12LEU)`. Basically `HD12LEU` should be converted to `HD12,LEU`.

This is how the file should look like.

```
ATOM,9,HG,LEU,1,162.4,131.44,219.19,0,0,PROA
ATOM,10,CD1,LEU,1,163.3,130.88,219.73,0,0,PROA
ATOM,11,HD11,LEU,1,163.54,130.77,219.97,0,0,PROA,
ATOM,12,HD12,LEU,1,163.48,130.98,219.76,0,0,PROA,
```

I want this to be done for all the lines in the file at once. Please suggest a way to do this in R/Python/Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible solution in Python ([regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/xjg1Yu/2)):

```py
import re


text = """\
ATOM,9,HG,LEU,1,162.4,131.44,219.19,0,0,PROA
ATOM,10,CD1,LEU,1,163.3,130.88,219.73,0,0,PROA
ATOM,11,HD11LEU,1,163.54,130.77,219.97,0,0,PROA,
ATOM,12,HD12LEU,1,163.48,130.98,219.76,0,0,PROA,"""

text = re.sub(
    r"^([^,]+,[^,]+,)([A-Z]+\d+)([A-Z]+)", r"\g<1>\g<2>,\g<3>", text, flags=re.M
)

print(text)
```

Prints:

```
ATOM,9,HG,LEU,1,162.4,131.44,219.19,0,0,PROA
ATOM,10,CD1,LEU,1,163.3,130.88,219.73,0,0,PROA
ATOM,11,HD11,LEU,1,163.54,130.77,219.97,0,0,PROA,
ATOM,12,HD12,LEU,1,163.48,130.98,219.76,0,0,PROA,
```

Answer (score 1):

R with `perl=TRUE` and Python with the PyPI regex module or any other language that uses the PCRE or Onigmo regex engine supports `\K`, which resets the regex pointer in the string to the current location and discards all previously-match characters from those returned by a match. If one of those is used one can replace (zero-width) matches of the following regular expression with a comma:

```
^(?:[^,]*,){2}[^\d,]*\d+\K(?=[^\d,])
```

where the flags `g` ("global", do not return after first match) and `m` ("multiline", `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of a line, respectively) set.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TbmoxP/1)

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
^         # match the beginning of a line
(?:       # begin a non-capture group
  [^,]*   # match zero or more chars other than a comma
  ,       # match a comma
)         # end non-capture group
{2}       # execute above non-capture group twice
[^\d,]*   # match zero or more chars other than a digit or comma
\d+       # match one or more digits
\K        # reset pointer location and discard all previously-consumed chars
(?=       # begin a positive lookahead
  [^\d,]  # march a character other than a digit or comma
)         # end the positive lookahead
```

One can also hover the cursor over each part of the expression at the link to obtain an explanation of its function.